# Getting C variables from R?

Tags: r, rodbc

Here's my problem. I want to know how many open RODBC connections I have in my R session. Perhaps this problem is related [Show all open RODBC connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25530363/show-all-open-rodbc-connections).

The thing is, I won't be able to use this if I do not assign my connections to a variable i.e. I do `odbcConnect()` instead of `channel<-odbcConnect()` as there would be no environmental variables created.

I've looked at the C code for the package RODBC and there seems to be a variable `nChannels` which contains an `int` of the number of open connections. Am I able to call this variable from R, or even using C functions?

How does R environments come into play here? Or is it totally unrelated? Any explanation will be appreciated as I'm extremely new in this area. Please advice if my logic in approaching this is wrong as well.

Comment: You can’t “call a variable”. You call *functions*. — Anyway, regarding your problem: *why* would you ever do `odbcConnect()`? As far as I understand the connection is just not useful if you don’t store it. This question feels like an [x/y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/1968).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input. I've changed the title to Getting C variables instead of calling it to make it clearer. I am working on a system where users are submitting their own code and yes, the proper way to have a database connection will be to store the connection.

But certain users are querying the database using `sqlQuery(odbcConnect(),"Select * from table")` which will open the connection and not close it. Worse still, if they run it in a loop, the database will be blocked due to too many open connections and it will require flushing.

Comment: What I am trying to do is to find a way to check the number of open connections on each Rsessions so that I know which users are opening connections without closing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If users are submitting their own code, the solution is simple: provide your *own* function `odbcConnect` which internally logs the call and then dispatches to the {RODBC} package. That is, don’t give users direct access to the RODBC package.

This works as long as you either provide the setup for the user (i.e. users are never expected to call `library(RODBC)`, nor `RODBC::odbcConnect`).

But if this isn’t the case, i.e. if users interact directly with the RODBC package, you’ll need to go one step further: you need to modify the RODBC package yourself. You can either do this by patching the function at runtime, but this is *fairly advanced* (and brittle; it breaks if RODBC upgrades and changes its implementation). Here’s a minimal example:

```
log_connect_expr = quote(assign('.odbc_connections', .GlobalEnv$.odbc_connections + 1, .GlobalEnv))
log_close_expr = quote(assign('.odbc_connections', .GlobalEnv$.odbc_connections - 1, .GlobalEnv))

# Inject expression into a function body at a given position, counting either
# from the beginning or from the end (if `pos` < 0).
insert_in_body = function (body, expr, pos) {
    body = as.list(body)
    if (pos < 0) pos = length(body) + pos + 1
    all_indices = seq_along(body)
    before_indices = all_indices < pos
    after_indices = all_indices >= pos
    as.call(c(body[before_indices], expr, body[after_indices]))
}

# Insert log calls into function bodies, after any error checking.

local({
    odbcDriverConnect = RODBC::odbcDriverConnect
    body(odbcDriverConnect) = insert_in_body(body(odbcDriverConnect), log_connect_expr, -1)
    odbcClose = RODBC::odbcClose
    body(odbcClose) = insert_in_body(body(odbcClose), log_close_expr, 4)

    assignInNamespace('odbcDriverConnect', odbcDriverConnect, getNamespace('RODBC'))
    assignInNamespace('odbcClose', odbcClose, getNamespace('RODBC'))
})

# Initialize counter
.GlobalEnv$.odbc_connections = 0
```

Alternative, just download the RODBC source code, modify it, build the package and install that locally. All these solutions are hacky, but better than rummaging around in the C internals of RODBC.

---

Reading the internal RODBC connection status isn’t practical. First off, the variable `nChannels` doesn’t seem to be an accurate count of the number of open connections; it’s more like an upper bound, and closing a connection does not decrease the counter.

But even if it were accurate, *you cannot read it anyway* because the variable is declared `static`, and therefore not exported.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed solution! But I just found an error with my approach. The part where the opening of connections are logged will work well but there are several ways a user can close connections. If the connection is assigned i.e. `channel = RODBC::odbcConnect()` it can be closed using the base function `close` as well. Non assigned connection variables can still be using `gc()` or `RODBC::odbcCloseAll()`. I guess the best method will be to log whenever a user opens a connection and see if it roughly corresponds to the number of processes in `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` for my dbms.

Comment: @TanJason Ouch, that’s painful. Unfortunately I don’t see a way around this. :-(