# Check if odbc connection is open or closed

Tags: r, database, odbc, database-connection

I want to write a function that runs the following operation: "if a database connection is already open, close it and reopen a new one"

To do this I need a way to check if the connection is already open

Here is my connection string:

```
library(odbc)

my_conn_string <- paste("Driver{Teradata};DBCName=teradata2690;DATABASE=PRODUCTION;UID=",
                            username,";PWD=",password, sep="")

t2690 <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), .connection_string=my_conn_string)
```

I thought about using the `class` of the connection:

```
    if (is.null(class(t2690)) { 
t2690 <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), .connection_string=my_conn_string) 
}
```

However this does not work as the class is the same whether the connection is open or not:

```
# Class when connected
class(t2690)

[1] "Teradata"
attr(,"package")
[1] ".GlobalEnv"

# Class when not connected
dbDisconnect(t2690)
class(t2690)

[1] "Teradata"
attr(,"package")
[1] ".GlobalEnv"
```

Comment: Have you seen this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25530363/show-all-open-rodbc-connections

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to adapt that answer to work with package `odbc` rather than `RODBC`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a function `DBI::dbIsValid`, which is imported by `odbc`. This provides a generic test returning a logical.

```
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")    
dbIsValid(con)
# TRUE

dbDisconnect(con)
dbIsValid(con)    
# FALSE
```

To reconnect a disconnected or cleared connection, you could conditionally connect based on this value, for example:

```
if (!dbIsValid(con)) {

  con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")

}
```